# How to unblock a specific date in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a school project and i need help.

It is a calendar management tool between a patient and a health professional.

I use fullcalendar to manage the calendar on my web application.

Our calendar must be parametrizable by professionals and usable by the clients.

Example: a professional opens from 8h to 18h from Monday to Friday. Saturdays and Sundays are locked (defined with business hour). How can I do if he wants to be open on Saturday May 21 knowing that the box is already grayed out by default? (with business hour).

Thank you !

Comment: You mean you want to override the businessHours with a specific exception? Is that right?

Comment: Yes @ADyson that's right. How can I do this?

Comment: As far as I know unfortunately it's not possible to make an exception like this using the fullCalendar API. Perhaps you could fake it by messing with the CSS or something.